# How do I mirror image and rotate a layer of points in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, point, rotate

I can't use the Rotate or Mirror tool since it's not a raster, and if I convert it to a group of rasters I lose the point labels. What can I do? Alternatively, is there a way to label a group of rasters in the way you'd label points?

Comment: Esri says to use the transform tool https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/faq-is-the-spatial-adjustment-toolbar-available-in-arcg-000026553 - add your from/to pairs and it will spin/flip/rotate your points as much as you need. If you need to you can do mirror/rotate on a raster and then use that to identify your 'to' coordinates.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to start off by understanding why your points need to be rotated and/or mirrored. Are the lat/lon reversed in the source data? Is there something else wrong?